# Is it possible to lazy-load and inject angular modules into the app in runtime using angularAMD?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-amd

I have ng-grid as a dependency when defining the app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
```

But not all my views and controllers need ngGrid, so I was thinking if it could be possible to load and inject ngGrid into the app while defining the controllers which need it?

I tried somthing like this, but it didn't work:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
```

ProductListCtrl.js:

```
define(['app', 'ng-grid'], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.register.controller('ProductListCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngGrid', function ($scope) {
        name = $injector.get('ngGrid')
        $scope.name = name
    }]);

});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angularAMD` provides an `ngload` RequireJS plugin allowing you to load existing AngularJS modules.  Add `ngload` to your `main.js` then do:

`define(['app', 'ngload!ng-grid'], function (app) { ... }`

See [documentation](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD#3rd-party-angularjs-modules) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I still cannot get it working. I don't have access to the Plunker, so I created a GitHub repo(https://github.com/chocstarfish/scalable-angular-app). Would you please take a minute and check it out for me. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the error it throws is like: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'factory' of undefined ng-grid-2.0.11.debug.js:209
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngGridProvider <- ngGrid

Comment: @NicolasZ you need to create something with just one page loading just ng-grid as I can't debug your whole app.  The error I see is "Unknown provider: simpleClockModuleProvider <- simpleClockModule".

Comment: At first I thought it was the problem of ngGrid directive because it contains serveral angular modules itself. So I added it another angular directive in the Home page, you can simply click the 'Product List' link or navigate to 'http://localhost:9000/#/functions/products' to see what happens with ngGrid, sorry for your inconvenience and thanks again for your patience!

Comment: There might be a problem with angularAMD but I need you update the repo loading ngGrid in app.js and a working "Product List".  I did it in the project but result is mingled.  I can't test until I know what the result should be.

Comment: I have created a new branch: https://github.com/chocstarfish/scalable-angular-app/tree/without_ngload, all the directives are working when I load them in the first place before app boots up.

Comment: There is a bug in the angularAMD which it is now fixed in the master branch.  I included the latest version in your project and pushed the working version to the branch you gave me.  You also needed to add jquery dependency to ng-grid.

Comment: Thank you! It finally works, I wish I could use bower to update the hotfix soon.